# What's wrong in my JAVA code?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to write the code for this question:

> You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write code to compute the result, encoded as an int value: 0=no ticket, 1=small ticket, 2=big ticket. If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the result is 2. Unless it is your birthday -- on that day, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

This is what I got and it doesn't compile.

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
  int noTicket = 0;
  int smallTicket = 1;
  int bigTicket = 2;

  if (speed <= 60) {
      return noTicket;
  } else if (speed >= 61 && speed <= 80) {
      return smallTicket;
  } else if (speed >= 81){
      return bigTicket;
  } else{
      return 8;
  }
  if (isBirthday) && (speed <= 65) {
      return noTicket;
  } else if (isBirthday) && (speed >= 66 && speed <= 86) {
      return smallTicket;
  } else if(isBirthday) && (speed >= 86) {
      return bigTicket;
  } else {
      return 7;
  } 
}
```

Comment: 1) It's not formatted legibly. 2) Read, think about, search for, and explain (compiler) error messages. 3) Hint: `if ( expression_inside_parenthesis )`

Comment: Tell us what error does the compiler throw when you compile this code

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Take @user2864740's hint and then come back and ask a specific question about why it isn't working. For example, why the `isBirthday` boolean isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
  int noTicket = 0;
  int smallTicket = 1;
  int bigTicket = 2;

  if (isBirthday && speed <= 65) {
      return noTicket;
  } else if (isBirthday && speed >= 66 && speed <= 86) {
      return smallTicket;
  } else if(isBirthday && speed >= 86) {
      return bigTicket;
  } else if (speed <= 60) {
      return noTicket;
  } else if (speed >= 61 && speed <= 80) {
      return smallTicket;
  } else if (speed >= 81){
      return bigTicket;
  } else{
      return 8;
  }
}
```

Note how `isBirthday` is composed with other conditions.

Answer (score 3):

If a Java compiler complains about your code, it almost always will tell you exactly what the problem is, and you should read the error message carefully (as well as showing it to those you ask help from).

In this particular case, it's probably complaining about unreachable code since, no matter *what* your speed is, it will return something from the first `if` block, meaning you cannot reach the second. I'm also unsure as to why you're returning `7` and `8` from your code when the specification mentions nothing about that possibility. The only reason your code would behave (were the compiler to accept it) is because that too is unreachable.

On top of that, the form of `if` statements you have in the second block:

```
if(isBirthday) && (speed <= 65){
```

are not valid. There needs to be parentheses around the *entire* expression, such as with:

```
if ((isBirthday) && (speed <= 65)) {
```

In my opinion, a better way to code this is to have a single set of `if` statements working out the fine and introducing a leniency buffer when it's your birthday.

I'm also not a big fan of the `if (x) return y else ...` construct since it introduces unnecessary code indentation. So I would be looking at something like (pseudo-code):

```
def fine(speed, isbirthday):
    if isbirthday:
        leniancy = 5
    else:
        leniency = 0

    if speed <= 60 + leniency:
        return 0

    if speed <= 80 + leniency:
        return 1

    return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The first **else if** block is outside the method body,  and that's clearly an error. It should be right after the first **if** block and inside the method body.  In fact your method body ends way before any of the **if-else** blocks end,  they all should be inside the method body.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the formatting issues, there is a logic issue.  You are checking for (isBirthday) **after** you have returned values.  This check needs to be done first.  Also, it looks like your code says to return no ticket if it is one's birthday, but the homework assignment :) looks like the result should be that you get a small ticket at the range of 66-85, and a big ticket at 86.